# Keep content below a fixed header using Jquery

Tags: jquery, css, resize, window, height

Here is a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/R4d57/7/) isolating my issue

I have a fixed header with floating content that has defined widths and heights, which increase the size of the header as the window gets smaller.

What I need is for the div with the class "page-bump" to always be the same height as the header so that the content below #header will line up flush with the bottom of #header.

Right now I have it so whenever the page is refreshed .page-bump gets a height assigned to it which is equal to the header, great!  However, it doesn't update as the window gets resized.
code below:

HTML

```
<div id="header">
<div class="thing1"></div>
<div class="thing2"></div>
</div>
<div class="page-bump"></div>
```

CSS

```
#header {
background-color:#0000FF;
width:100%;
position:fixed;
}
.thing1 {
float:left;
background-color:#a7a7a7;
width:300px;
height:50px;
}
.thing2 {
float:left;
background-color:#f2f2f2;
width:300px;
height:50px;
}
```

Javascript/Jquery

```
var pageBump = function () {
var headerHeight = $('#header').height();
$('.page-bump').css('height',headerHeight);
};
$(window).resize(pageBump());
```

Any suggestions?  Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It should be $(window).resize(pageBump);

Comment: I've never seen that kind of synthax so you may be right, but try maybe $(window).resize(function()
{
  pageBump();
});

Comment: How do you know it's not updated if header is same size on load and on resize?